# Underline a section header the full width of the page

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, sectsty

How do I get a full page width underline or bottom-border on a section title?

At the moment I'm using

```
\usepackage{sectsty}  
\sectionfont{\normalfont\sffamily\large\underline\bfseries\color{orange}}
```

but that only underlines the text.  I want the line to stretch the entire width of the page.  Can I do it in the font definition or do I have to play with the rendering of `\section`?

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4758/215)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [sectsty package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/sectsty.html) provides mechanisms to add rules, rather than to use underlining as you have done. See section 8.2 of the manual.

Alternatively, the [titlesec package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/titlesec.html) seems to offer like facilities, described in section 3.4 of the manual.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Sec 8.2 helped a lot.  I now have \sectionfont{\normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries\color{orange}\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-4pt}{1pt}}.

Comment: @Adam: You are welcome and I am glad it helped. I'm also glad to have my answer accepted. But, in future, it is better, I think, to wait a bit before accepting. You might find that an even better answer shows up if you do so. The acceptance does somewhat discourage others from adding answers.