# Changing the section title style for an article document type

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, article, sectsty

I have just started working on my master's thesis with my universities latex template. It uses the 'article' document class for it. I have tweaked it here and there a bit to make it more to my liking. I wanted to change the way the section headers looked like to make it look better.

So, I want to be able to change the font and font size, style etc. I would also like to add horizontal lines to give it more style. It would roughly look like this:

```
-------------------
   INTRODUCTION
-------------------
```

Well something with more decoration than the default style atleast.

Can anyone tell me how can I make these changes? I would also be useful if I can find some already implemented section styles.

Comment: Your university thesis template is the article document class!? Is this a Master's thesis? Because for a PhD thesis, article class is a bad idea...

Comment: @Seamus yah its a Masters thesis template.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/) package or [secsty](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sectsty/) might have the resources you need.

If it's a longer project, look at the [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) document class, which has more options, but will involve more work to conform to university guidelines.

Here's a very quick `sectsty` version of what you want.

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{%
\sectionrule{2ex}{1pt}{-1ex}{1pt}%
}
```

And to do roughly the same thing with `titlesec` do the following:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\titlerule%
  \normalfont\bfseries\Large}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}[\titlerule]
```

I think I prefer the titlesec version, because titlesec is a better overall package, in my opinion. If you want to change the thickness of the titlerules here, the second one breaks if you add an argument to it. So put `\newcommand{\trule}{\titlerule[1pt]}` or whatever thickness you want between the `\usepackage` and the `\titleformat` commands. Then replace each `\titlerule` with `\trule`.

As for a memoir version? Work it out yourself! The memoir documentation is excellent.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the titlesec package. It comes with quite many features that are definitely useful for you. Also, if I remember correctly, there are examples of usage in the appendix of the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/titlesec.html).