# Underline the title of a subsection

Tags: sectioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the section title style for an article document type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/changing-the-section-title-style-for-an-article-document-type)

I'm trying to undeline the title of a set of subsections in my document. In order to achieve it, I have defined a new environment that encapsulates the format of this subsection.

My problem is that I can not achieve to underline the text of the title of the subsection. 
I don't want to use the package `sectsty` because if I do this I have conflicts with other definitions done using the `titlesec` package.

```
\newenvironment{UnderlineSubSection}{  
    \titleformat{\subsection}  
    {\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\color{cyan}}  
    {\thesection}{1em}{}  
}{}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please think twice about this. Underlining is really ugly.

Comment: Load for example the [`ulem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulem) package and add `\uline` to the last argument (i.e the one after `{1em}`) of `\titleformat`.

Comment: @user17888 Good typography (see _Bringhurst_) recommend to use _italic_, not underline. Underline was used in manuscripts typed on a typewriter to indicate for the printing house that the text should be set in _italic_. So only use underlining if your boss sacks you if you are not using it.

Answer (score 4):

define it as a command, just as the default subsection. Instead of package `soul` you can use `ulem` alternetively

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{soul}

\makeatletter
\def\UnderlineSubSection{\@ifnextchar*\UnderlineSubSection@i\UnderlineSubSection@ii}
\def\UnderlineSubSection@i*#1{\subsection*{\ul{#1}}}
\def\UnderlineSubSection@ii{\@ifnextchar[\UnderlineSubSection@iii\UnderlineSubSection@iv}
\def\UnderlineSubSection@iii[#1]#2{\subsection[#1]{\ul{#2}}}
\def\UnderlineSubSection@iv#1{\subsection{\ul{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}  

\tableofcontents

\section{foo}
\subsection{foo}
\UnderlineSubSection{baz}
\UnderlineSubSection*{foobar}
\UnderlineSubSection[foobarbaz]{foo\_bar\_baz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user17888 please consider accepting Herbert's answer (by clicking on the check-mark to the left of the answer, below its vote count).